# Java Map merge vs computeIfAbsent and computeIfPresent

Tags: java, java-8, concurrenthashmap

I have used compute method as well as merge method.
However I am still not sure how merge method differs from compute methods.

I was asked a question in interview to maintain a counter of hits for given list of IP addresses. It was a basic implementation of Map where key is the IP and value is the number of hits.

I implemented it with computeIfAbsent method but that was not sufficient when the key is present so I had to change the implementation to use merge method.

Can we say that merge is equivalent to using both compute methods at same time?

Answer (score 4):

Well yes logically it is, you could say that it is equivalent to:

```
merge(){
   computeIfAbsent(...)
   computeIfPresent(...)
}
```

but of course they have different implementations

Comment: A difference is that `merge` always receives the value, while `computeIf*` allows to create a new value lazily.